# How to print the line number where a string appears in a file?

Tags: shell, awk

I have a specific word, and I would like to find out what line number in my file that word appears on.

This is happening in a c shell script.

I've been trying to play around with awk to find the line number, but so far I haven't been able to. I want to assign that line number to a variable as well.

Comment: Don't write c shell scripts. Google `CSH why not`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Using grep

To look for `word` in file and print the line number, use the `-n` option to `grep`:

```
grep -n 'word' file
```

This prints both the line number and the line on which it matches.

### Using awk

This will print the number of line on which the word `word` appears in the file:

```
awk '/word/{print NR}' file
```

This will print both the line number and the line on which `word` appears:

```
awk '/word/{print NR, $0}' file
```

You can replace `word` with any regular expression that you like.

How it works:

- `/word/`

  This selects lines containing `word`.
- `{print NR}`

  For the selected lines, this prints the line number (NR means Number of the Record).  You can change this to print any information that you are interested in.  Thus, `{print NR, $0}` would print the line number followed by the line itself, `$0`.

### Assigning the line number to a variable

Use command substitution:

```
n=$(awk '/word/{print NR}' file)
```

### Using shell variables as the pattern

Suppose that the regex that we are looking for is in the shell variable `url`:

```
awk -v x="$url" '$0~x {print NR}' file
```

And:

```
n=$(awk -v x="$url" '$0~x {print NR}' file)
```

Comment: the expression im trying to match is saved in a variable, so I'm doing $url in place of word. Is that going to cause an error?

Comment: @Taylor Yes, you have to be careful how that is done.  The best way is to use the `-v` option to assign the shell variable `url` to an awk variable and then use the awk variable for regex matching.  See the new section at the end of the answer.

Comment: can the contents of another file be used in place of `word` ?

Comment: @AruniRC Yes.  For example, `grep -nf file1 file2` will print every line (along with its line number) in file2 that matches any one of the lines in file1.  The lines in file1 are treated as regular expressions,  If you don't want that, use  `grep -nFf file1 file2` to look for literal (non-regex) matches instead.

Answer (score 3):

**Sed**

You can use the sed command

```
 sed -n '/pattern/=' file
```

**Explanation**

The `-n` suppresses normal output so it doesn't print the actual lines. It first matches the `/pattern/`, and then the `=` operator means print the line number. Note that this will print all lines that contains the pattern.

Comment: To follow up on that, as my pattern I want to use a variable named "url" so when I type this command I do sed $url= file.txt, but it doesn't work because of the $ i presume. Is there any way around that?

Comment: To use shell variables, use double quotes so
`sed -n "/$url/=" file.txt`

Comment: I am getting the following error message: sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command

Comment: What is the value of `$url`? If it contains any special characters like `/` slashes then we need to change the delimiter for the sed commannd.

Comment: I'm assuming the value `$url` has no commas. Try `sed -n "\,$url,=" file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

### Use the NR Variable

Given a file containing:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

use the built-in [NR variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Records.html#index-NR-variable) to find the line number. For example:

```
$ awk '/bar/ { print NR }' /tmp/foo
2
```

Answer (score 0):

find the line number for which the first column match RRBS

```
awk 'i++ {if($1~/RRBS/) print i}' ../../bak/bak.db
```