# How to find a particular func1 and go the previous func2 just above func1 and make it in some format?

Tags: shell, awk, command-line

I want to create a script which searches for a pattern `func1(some--condition, "");` and go to the string just above it with pattern `var = func2(some--text);` then print `func1(some--condition, "func2 some-text; var");`.

I tried to grep func1(.*, ""); and pipe awk.

Search for 
func1(some--condition, "");  //Example

Then search for this, (just above func1();)
var = func2(some--text); //Example

Then make func1 as
func1(some--condition, "func2() some--text; any");

Demo input source.c

```
var = func2(some--text);
func1(some--condition, "");
```

Demo Output source.c

```
var = func2(some--text);
func1(some--condition, "func2 some--text; var");
```

Comment: please provide demo input, demo output.

Comment: You should seriously look into the formatting options given by SO. Seriously ! They are great

Comment: I thin [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658703/how-to-print-the-line-number-where-a-string-appears-in-a-file) post will help you to resolve issue.

Comment: I have updated the description that I want a create a script that will do it for me. And I checked the post, but can't figure out. @NileshGodhani